# jquery get can't find any good examples

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a line of code in example.html there is other code but I only want to get his bit

```
     <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
```

I also I have another html page test.html where I want to do a jquery get which gets the piece of code and prints it out onto the test.html.
I cannot find a decent website that explains it well.
If anyone knows of a good website or can give me a good explanation, that would be more appreciated then giving me the answer

Comment: Navigate to http://learn.jquery.com There is a chapter about ajax.

Comment: hi, please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see an example here:

http://jsbin.com/kayey/1/edit?html,output

First of all you'll need to make a get request to get file contents and then, set the content of the file to the "container" on test.html file:

```
$.get('example.html', function(response){
    $('#content').html(response);
});
```

All this inside your test.html file that would have a div#content element or the one that you want.

Regards, I hope it works.